# Adding AJAX to Rails 3 app causes no error messages to show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

When adding `:remote => true` to my edit form in my rails app, submits work fine, but now my program does not show error messages. I have tried multiple solutions but none of them have worked. Can anyone point me in the correct direction to solve this problem? If the entry is successfully saved, a notice message is added to a div, something I wrote in edit.js.erb. I tried to also have the 'error messages' added to an error message div but `@entry.errors.any?` never returns true when I add `:remote => true`.

This is the edit div in my form I am trying to update.

```
<div id="errors">
  <% if @entry.errors.any? %>
      <h2><%= pluralize(@entry.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this entry from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @entry.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I also have its contents in a partial and my edit.js.erb tries to update the div with the newly rendered partial, but now @entry.errors.any? is not returning true here anymore.. Here is also my controller...

```
# GET /entries/1/edit
def edit
  @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end


def update
  @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @entry.update_attributes(params[:entry])
      format.html { redirect_to edit_entry_path(@entry), notice: 'Entry was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a partial, **_errors.html.erb**

```
<% if @entry.errors.any? %>
    <h2><%= pluralize(@entry.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this entry from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @entry.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

I created **update.js.erb**

```
$("#errorlist").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('errors')) %>");
```

where #errors refers to a  in my form, and the errors partial. Finally my controller is like this now.
  # PUT /entries/1
  # PUT /entries/1.json
  def update
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])

```
def update
  @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @entry.update_attributes(params[:entry])
      format.html { redirect_to edit_entry_path(@entry), notice: 'Entry was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Also, since I only want ajax on my edit form, and not my create form (adding :remote => true to _form.html.erb effects both) I also changed this line in _form.html.erb from

```
<%= form_for @entry, :remote => true, :html => {:id => "editform", :multipart => true} do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for @entry, :remote => current_page?(:controller => 'entries', :action => 'new') ? false : true, :html => {:id => "editform", :multipart => true} do |f| %>
```

Thank you for the help, those who helped me achieve my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could change your controller to this :

```
def update
  @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @entry.update_attributes(params[:entry])
      format.html { redirect_to edit_entry_path(@entry), notice: 'Entry was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

create a app/views/my_controllers/update.js.erb and put something like this :

```
//Just normal javascript and some JS
errors = '';
<% @entry.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  errors += '<%= msg %>\n';
<% end %>
alert(errors);
```

**Edit : Add a second method**

You can also do this :

```
$("#my_form")
 .bind("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
  //Do my function
});
```

Comment: Neither of these solutions worked for me. My application acts the exact same... any ideas? Also, anything I put in update.js.erb does not even do anything it looks like? All of my previous code has been in edit.js.erb and it looks like that code does get rendered when I push my submit button.

Comment: replace this `format.js` by this `format.js :format => :js`. Is there an ajax request when you submit the form?

Comment: I eventually got things working Dougui. Thank you for your help, I will post my solution, but mark yours up because although it did not work for me exactly it got me on the right track, and I'm sure your code still works under your possible given scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You want to respond to `format.js` and add the error rendering to your.js.erb

Responding to `.json` will return just data therefore won't run its response.

Comment: I changed format.json {...} in my update controller to format.js. Unfortunately, my application still acts the same. Also, in my controller there is an edit function that already was responding with format.js. In fact, making changes to update.js.erb don't even show up when I hit submit. Only whatever was in edit.js.erb...

Comment: What happens if you clear the whole `update` controller logic and let it pass straight through to update.js.erb will your changes be seen then?  If it doesn't run update.js.erb it may be a problem with your routes

Comment: You were correct on the first part. Nothing was wrong with my routes, was just my controller. But after some hacking I eventually got it to work. I think the error was in the html: {render action: edit } before format.js. I don't think it was ever actually doing the format.js line.